# Multiprocessing API call using columns of Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-requests, multiprocessing

I've just started working with the `multiprocessing` Python library. I would like to make many API calls (get) using `requests`. I have a `Pandas` dataframe in which each row has the arguments I will be using to process the `requests.get`.

Here is an example of the dataframe I want to `starmap` to.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {
    "companyId": ['1000','1005'],
    "headers": [{'Authorization': 'Bearer token1'},{'Authorization': 'Bearer token1'}],
    "employeeId": ['1500','1500'],
    "date": ['2022-01-01','2022-01-02']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.head()
```

Code to make request:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def get_data(df: pd.DataFrame):
    query: dict = {
        'companyId': df['companyId'].astype(str),
        'driverId': df['employeeId'].astype(str),
        'day': df['date'].astype(str)
    }
    resp = requests.get(url=df['url'], headers=df['headers'], params=query)
    return resp

if __name__ == "__main__":
     with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as p:
          res = list(p.starmap(get_data, zip(df.itertuples())))
          print(res)
          p.close()
          p.join()
```

However, I receive some errors I am trying to understand. Ultimately, I want to map the api function to each row of my pandas dataframe in a parallel fashion. I would prefer to just use the multiprocessing library but do not necessarily need to use `Pandas` here if there is a simpler and more native solution.

Comment: Any reason why you want to use multi processing? Seems to be an IO bound and not a CPU bound problem which means you could use multithreading or asyncio with an async client like httpx.

Comment: @SimonHawe Am hitting an API endpoint thousands of times and in a for loop fashion it takes a long period of time to process.

Comment: Your code give me a pickling error that is related to the type of data return by `itertuples`. looking around seems to advice to change to `list` instead of pandas frame. But then you need to rewrite your function to accept a list as parameter. I have never use multithreading so not sure what are the best practice, but maybe even better would be to change `zip(df.itertuples())`  by `df.to_dict(orient='records')`, then ensure that `get_data` get a dictionary as input, each time you feed a dictionary with the columns as keys and a value per row

Comment: @Ben.T I think I may have just figured out the error but I'd still probably prefer a non-Pandas solution.

Comment: Yeah I know, still multi threading or asyncio would be better suited as you can fire more requests in parallel as compared to using multiprocessing. With that you are bound to the number of processors your machine has.